# NW.js + TypeScript: Cannot find module 'nw.gui'

Tags: typescript, nwjs

I am trying to use **TypeScript** in an existing *NW.js + JS* project.
Since I am new to NW.js, I naively assumed it works out of the box after installing the [nw.gui typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/nw.gui).
It doesn't (as TypeScript does not recognize the global `nw` variable).

```
import * as nw from 'nw.gui';
```

Gives me

> Cannot find module 'nw.gui'

How do I setup my code to work properly with NW.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround which lets me use the global **nw** variable from NW.js: `declare var nw: any;`

The compiler doesn't complain anymore. I don't get any type information, but I can live with that and just use it as I would in JS.

Answer (score 0):

install the package `@types/nw.gui`

then on a file called `nw.d.ts` put `declare var nw: typeof import('nw.gui')`

then voalá! works like a charm!

[image]